# Can I have OpenGL work in mono-color channel mode?

Tags: opengl, render-to-texture

I'm writing some 2D convolution effects, and some of them only needs one channel of color. Although I know how to create `GL_RED` textures which are single-channel, I don't know how to make rest of OpenGL rendering pipeline working in single-channel: for example, `glClearColor` always specify four color components. Actually, I don't even know whether it is valid to bind a single-channel `GL_RED` texture to an FBO's color attachment.

As a backup option, I can still work in RGBA and only use one channel. But it would be four times waste of graphic memory and I don't like it.

I know there's indexed color mode. However it is complex and deprecated, so I don't want to use it.

Comment: Rendering to GL_RED textures should work without problems. The unused values of `glClearColor` are ignored. What other functions do you have trouble with?

Comment: "some 2D convolution effects" you may look into compute shaders.

Comment: @BDL Mostly in GLSL. For example, `texture` function always return `vec4` result, and `gl_FragColor` is always an `vec4`. Should I just use the *red* component and simply ignore others?

Comment: @ybungalobill compute shaders are induced in OpenGL 4.X. As not all drivers support that, I cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

After some experiments, OpenGL works properly with non-RGBA channels. For `GL_RED`, the redundant green, blue and alpha channels in `glClearColor` arguments, `texture` return vector and `gl_FragColor` builtin are just silently ignored/discarded.